# socat tun device very low throughput

Tags: tcp, network-speed, iperf, tun, socat

I was tinkering around with socat and tried to use socat for creating a TUN device for tunneling between two debian stretch servers. However, throughput seemed very low and comparing with iperf against TCP/TCP-Listen on localhost, TUN has about 5 orders of magnitude less throughput.

Here is a "minimum working example" to show how speed is affected.

## socat with TUN device

#### Server side:

```
# socat
socat TUN:10.10.0.2/16,iff-up TCP4-LISTEN:54321,bind=192.168.1.2,fork
# iperf service
iperf -s -p 15001 -B 10.10.0.2
```

#### Client side:

```
# socat
socat TUN:10.10.0.1/16,iff-up TCP4:192.168.1.2:54321
# iperf
iperf -c 10.10.0.2 -p 15001 -t 30
```

## socat with TCP/TCP-LISTEN

#### Server side:

```
# socat
socat TCP4-LISTEN:12345,bind=192.168.1.2,fork TCP4:127.0.0.1:15001
# iperf service
iperf -s -p 15001 -B 127.0.0.1
```

#### Client side:

```
# socat
socat TCP4-LISTEN:54321,bind=127.0.0.1,fork TCP4:192.168.1.2:12345
# iperf
iperf -c 127.0.0.1 -p 54321 -t 30
```

## Results

#### TUN device:

```
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3]  0.0-39.7 sec   640 KBytes   132 Kbits/sec
```

#### TCP/TCP-LISTEN:

```
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3]  0.0-30.0 sec  3.30 GBytes   944 Mbits/sec
```

If you want to reproduce the results using the lines above, you need to somehow run socat lines and the iperf serverside in the background or daemonized, I just used screen sessions.

So, while I assumed that throughput will suffer to some degree, it seems strange to me that it will degrade from the assumed gigabit (both servers on same switch) to a mere 100KBit. A quick glance at `atop` shows no significant bottlenecks, so it isn't just CPU capped or eating RAM.

**Why is throughput that low?** Some logic error I did? Or a problem in the kernel, bad implementation in socat, or using iperf wrong?

Are there any parameters or settings (kernel, socat, anything) to improve this? Anything I could check for? And, most important, is there a way I can use the TUN device which gives me useful throughput?

Comment: I've noticed the same exact problem. I did not test the throughput but performing a simple unencrypted HTTP request with 600b of response is ~300ms over socat TUN-TCP tunnel and 5ms via other kind of tunnel. Everything is happening on the same physical host. I've tried playing with MTU and txqueuelen to no avail. I don't see packet drops or errors. Will take a stab at this with tcpdump later. So far an educated guess would be an increased round-trip time due to some kind of blocking (half-duplex?). I need to check if socat uses threading or async IO on both ends (Macos/Alpine Linux)

Comment: Did you try `nodelay` option to `TCP4` and  `TCP-LISTEN`?

Answer (score 3):

I was having a similar issue when using `socat` to create an IP connection between two computers using a Bluetooth serial connection (via `rfcomm`). The raw serial connection was rather fast (15 or so KiB/s), but when connecting to a web server via the TUN device created by socat, the speed was very slow and the browser eventually just gave up after loading for a while.

The socat man page does say the following.

```
Note that streaming eg. via TCP or SSL does not guarantee to retain packet boundaries and may thus cause packet loss.
```

This made me wonder if packets were being dropped or truncated. Sure enough, `tcpdump -i tun0` showed many packets that were missing bytes (some missing over 140 bytes). Looking at the MTU (maximum transmission unit - packet size) of `tun0`, I found it was 1500 (`ip link`). However, the bluetooth MTU was 1021 (?) bytes according to `hciconfig --all` (if I am reading its output correctly).

Thus, for testing, I reduced the MTU on `tun0` (on both sides of the tunnel - on both computers) to 100 bytes. This worked ... well, it was still not super fast, but I was connected over Bluetooth and it was much faster than before. At least I did not get any connection issues anymore. Note that this can probably be set much larger, but I was just testing to see if it would fix the issue.

Below is the command to update the MTU on the `tun0` device created by socat (after calling socat) to be 100 bytes. This needs to be run on both systems (and probably should match).

```sh
ip link set mtu 100 tun0
```

Thus, you would execute the following.

## Server side:

```sh
# socat
socat TUN:10.10.0.2/16,iff-up TCP4-LISTEN:54321,bind=192.168.1.2,fork

# set MTU to 100
ip link set mtu 100 tun0

# iperf service
iperf -s -p 15001 -B 10.10.0.2
```

## Client side:

```sh
# socat
socat TUN:10.10.0.1/16,iff-up TCP4:192.168.1.2:54321

# Set MTU to 100
ip link set mtu 100 tun0

# iperf
iperf -c 10.10.0.2 -p 15001 -t 30
```

*Note: you can use `ip link` to show all links - look for `tun` to find the right device if `tun0` does not work.*